# How to edit access bits conditon in read only sector - Mifare Classic Tag

Tags: tags, key, nfc, rfid, mifare

I inserted in the tag some data but I was wrong in defining the access bits.
To be more specific, the sector 3 now is a read only sector, is there a way to change them?
I can't attach the image, [so here's the link][1]

Thanks for help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pTMM.png

Comment: For next question you should provider more details, like the command you´ve sent aso

Answer (score 0):

yeah… absolutely not.
unless you’re using a card that accepts chinese magic back door commands it’s fully locked. read only till it’s turned into ash.

it’s a hard lesson to learn but at least now you know to always check what you’re writing to where and to make sure the ACB are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your new accesses. This cannot be undone.

[image]